# Any vector space is a linear map image of a free vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field, and $S\neq \emptyset$ a set. The *free vector space* of $S$ is the set of all functions $f$ from $S$ to $\mathbb{F}$ such that $f(x)=0$ for all but finitely many $x\in S$, denoted $C(S)$. It is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ under usual addition and scalar multiplication.

In group theory, any group is a homomorphism image of some free group. I am wondering if it is analogously true for vector spaces, i.e., for all vector spaces $V$ over $\mathbb{F}$, there exists a set $S$ and a linear map $T\colon C(S)\to V$ such that $T$ is surjective.

Comment: Even better: **Every vector space is free** -- at least if you believe in the axiom of choice which implies that every vector space has a Hamel basis.

Comment: Yes (**even without choice**): set $S=V$, and consider $T(f)=\sum_{x \in V}{f(x)x}$.

Comment: @Mindlack I don't think your summation is well defined.

Comment: It's true more generally for modules.

Comment: @P.Quinton It is, because it's actually finite, given the hypothesis on $f$.

Comment: @CaptainLama right, thank you.

Comment: @Mindlack Many thanks!